The support of a coherent sheaf is not the whole space implies its dual is trivial
I am reading Huybrechts-Lehn's book The Geometry of Moduli Space of Sheaves. They claimed on page 6 that for a coherent sheaf $E$ on a smooth projective variety $X$, if the dimension of $E$ is less than the dimension of $X$, then its dual $\mathscr{H}om(E,\mathcal{O}_X)$ is trivial.
I don't see why. As far as I know, $E^{\vee}_x = \operatorname{Hom}(E_x,\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ and thus $\operatorname{Supp} E^{\vee}\subset \operatorname{Supp} E$. Since $E \cong (E^{\vee})^{\vee}$, $\operatorname{Supp}E = \operatorname{Supp}E^{\vee}$. So if $E$ is not trivial, then either is $E^{\vee}$.
Can someone explain why the statement holds and point out the error in my statement? Thanks a lot.

If $M$ is a torsion $R$-module, and $R$ is an integral domain, what is $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, R)$?

I don’t mean to be rude, but this is the second question you’ve asked about the first few pages of this book which is surely the introduction. If they are making statements which are confusing you this much, would it not be better to spend sometime reviewing the pre requisite material?

Dear Chris, I admit that sometimes I get confused with basic ideas and I will work on that. I tried to find answers by myself before asking the question. But when I get confused, it is better to ask stupid questions instead of leaving the question behind, right?

Your error is in the assertion $ E \cong (E^{\vee})^{\vee} $ which fails to hold for coherent sheaves in general.
You should work locally so that it becomes a commutative algebra question as in Daniel’s idea in the comments. Because $ E $ is supported on a closed subset of strictly lower dimension, it is given by a torsion $ R $-module $ M $ on an affine open $ \operatorname{Spec} R $. Conclude that $ Hom_R(M,R) $ is $ 0 $ because a torsion element can only map to $ 0 $ by the integral domain hypothesis.
